# Problems with programmatically selecting node in jsTree on page start-up

Tags: jstree

I can't select a tree element on page start-up. There is a JSFiddle with the setup: https://jsfiddle.net/voltel/aszn3h46/

My data is JSON array:

```
    const a_data = [
      {
        "id": "1296",
        "text": "Disposable and Single-Use Medical Supplies",
        "children": null
      },
      {
        "id": "1275",
        "text": "Implantables",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "1276",
            "text": "Defibrillators, Implantable",
            "children": null
          },
          {
            "id": "1338",
            "text": "Analysers, Laboratory In-Vitro Diagnostic, Clinical Chemistry, Manual",
            "children": null
          },
        ]}  
    ];

    // Rest of JavaScript code 

    const $tree = $("#display");

    $tree.jstree({
      'plugins' : [ "wholerow", "checkbox" ],
      'core': {
        data : a_data
      },
      'checkbox': {
        three_state: false
      },
    });
    //

    // The problem: I can't select/check node with this id
    const c_icd_device_type = "1338";

    // show initial value
    if (c_icd_device_type) {
      console.log(`Request to select node with id ${c_icd_device_type}`);

      const o_selected_node = $tree.jstree('get_node', c_icd_device_type);
      console.log('Selected node: ', o_selected_node);

        // Uncomment ONE of the following: 
      if (o_selected_node) {
        $tree.jstree('select_node', o_selected_node, true);
      } else {
          $tree.jstree(true).select_node(c_icd_device_type);
      }//endif
    }//endif
```

Please, help select a node on start-up, and get rid of some suspicious errors in console (see JSFiddle).

Now, I understand from other questions on jsTree here on StackOverflow, that if wrap my code selecting an element in an event handler, it works. I don't quite understand why it is so complicated, provided there are no asynchronous calls. And if it's unavoidable, why not use Promise?

```
$tree.on('ready.jstree', function (e, data) {
  console.log(`Request to select node with id ${c_icd_device_type}`);

  const o_selected_node = data.instance.get_node(c_icd_device_type);
  //const o_selected_node = $tree.jstree('get_node', c_icd_device_type);

  console.log('Selected node: ', o_selected_node);

    // Uncomment ONE of the following: 
  if (o_selected_node) {
    $tree.jstree('select_node', o_selected_node, true);
  } else {
      $tree.jstree(true).select_node(c_icd_device_type);
  }//endif

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any errors in console on Chrome:

Your code is fine. It just that the tree isn't ready yet. If you wrap your existing code inside ready.jstree event, it'll work.

```
$tree.on('ready.jstree', function (e, data) {

    // Copy line 38 onward and place your existing code here

});
```

Comment: Check console of the Firefox

Comment: I don't see any errors in console on Firefox either.